# IPTABLES: Blocking port to external users only

Tags: networking, iptables, port, docker

I have a server with two docker containers running. One of them is the frontend of a small application, served with `http-server`. This application used Javascript fetch API to fetch data from a really simple database based on Node.js 'json-server' module, which is running in the other container.

It happens that `json-server` makes port 3000 available to external user, i.e., if someone points a browser to `http://example.com:3000`, my data will be available without the filtering and presentation provided  by the frontend. This is not what I want.

I would like to block port 3000 to the exterior world, while allowing my other docker container to fetch data as usual. I think this may be done on a IP basis, but I don't know how to do it.

This is my current Iptables configuration, mostly created by Docker itself as a standard.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:3000

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

In the configuration above, IP 172.17.0.2 is my frontend application, while 172.17.0.3 is the IP of my database container.

The frontend container is being started with

```
docker run -p 80:8080 --name=frontend -d mtr/frontend
```

and the second one with

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 --name=database -d mtr/database
```

I also considered the possibility of having some Docker way to make this access restrict, but after a lot of research I couldn't find anything.

Any suggestions about how I may do this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you "ACCEPT" "tcp" connections from "anywhere" to the host "172.17.0.3" on "tcp" port "dpt:3000" and I guess there is also a DNAT rule which forwards every incoming connections to "you-public-ip-address:3000" to "172.17.0.3:3000" (see `iptables -t nat -L --line-numbers`) that's considered normal.

Remove the DNAT rule from the NAT table.

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING <the-dnat-rule-number>
```